# How can I auto filter out "0:00" in excel 2010?

Tags: excel

I am wondering if someone is able to assist me with the below code

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Y$993").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="0:00"
```

Recording a macro that I found that I can filter in 0:00 with the above code however what I want in actuality is to have it unchecked.

I tried the below code to no avail

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Y$993").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="<>0:00"
```

Is there some other code that I can use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the underlying values are dates and times formatted to only show the time. Time cannot be negative but to filter out *0:00* any of these should do: `, Criteria1:=">0:00"`  `, Criteria1:="<>0:00"` `, Criteria1:=">0"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked.

```
With ActiveSheet

    .Range("$A$1:$Y$993").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=">" & 1 / 10 ^ 10
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If you switch on the macro recorder and then perform the AutoFilter manually, you will see that Excel will build an array of the *allowed* values *(that is all the values except zero)* and apply that array as a Criteria.
You can do the same.

**EDIT**

Say we have:

[image]

We want to see all **except DarthVader**
This small macro follows the suggestion:

1. build a Collection of the "good" values
2. build a zero-based Variant array from the Collection
3. use the array in a filter

   Sub NotDarthVader()
       Dim c As Collection, tabl As Range
       Dim rLook As Range, r As Range
       Dim ary()

   ```
   Set c = New Collection
   Set tabl = Range("A1:C24")
   Set rLook = Intersect(Range("B:B"), tabl)
   Set rLook = Intersect(rLook, rLook.Offset(1, 0))

   On Error Resume Next
       For Each r In rLook
           v = r.Value
           If v <> "DarthVader" Then
               c.Add v, CStr(v)
           End If
       Next r
   On Error GoTo 0

   ReDim ary(0 To c.Count - 1)
   For i = 1 To c.Count
       ary(i - 1) = c.Item(i)
   Next i

   tabl.AutoFilter
   tabl.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=(ary), Operator:=xlFilterValues
   ```

   End Sub

Comment: Would you like an example??